# Calculate the matrix equation to find $a, b$ and $c$.

Tags: matrix-equations

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 \\
        1 & -2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & - 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix} $
and $I$ be the identity matrix. If $6A^-=aA^2+bA+cI$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers, then obtain the value of $(a,b,c).$

Options are: a) (1,2,1), b) (1,-1,2), c) (4,1,1), d) (1,4,1)

Calculate this with proper explanation and minimal working please. I am new to this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am learning to use MathJax. I have started new so i found it easier to post a pic in stead. But i surely will as soon as i learn it.

Comment: use cayley hamilton theorem

Comment: In the link posted by José you can find an example how to write a matrix. Everything else can be found there as well.

Comment: I have edited the question using MathJax. Hope it's not a problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(t)=a_3t^3+a_2t^2+a_1t+a_0$ is the char. polynomial of $A$, then , by Cayley -Hamilton:

$a_3A^3+a_2A^2+a_1A+a_0I=0$.

Compute $a_3,a_2,a_1$ and $a_0$. You will see thatb $a_0 \ne 0$.

This gives:

$a_0A^{-1}=a_3A^2+a_2A+a_1I$

Your turn !

Comment: I solved the characteristic equation and after substituting the matrix $A$ in it  (using Caley Hamilton theorem)I got $$A^3+4A^2+A=6I$$; then I operated by $A^{-1}$ on both sides to obtain $$(a,b,c)=(1,4,1)$$. That solved my question. Thanks a lot sir!